# Position element through css

Tags: javascript, jquery

what part of my code is wrong I keep getting invalid argument

I want to position the div element outside the document window on the left.

```
jQuery(this).css({"left": (jQuery(document).css("left") - jQuery(form).width())});
```

Comment: I don't recall seeing a left() function in jQuery. Maybe you need to use .css("left") to get the value

Comment: I changed it to jQuery(document).css("left") and I get the error style is not an object

Comment: Are you double posting??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531568/need-to-position-div-element-outside-document-area-not-working

Answer (score 1):

`document` is the HTMLDocument instance. It's not an HTMLElement instance so no CSS styles apply to it. Consequently you can't read any `left` style from it. You can try `document.documentElement` (or `$('html')`) to get the root element child of the document, but I'm not sure what use you think reading its `left` style will be. (In reality: you'll get nothing.)

Are you really trying to position a div *outside* of the browser window? Obviously this cannot work; the whole idea of the window is that it constrains, clips and scrolls the document content inside it.

If you wanted to display content outside of the current browser window you would have to `window.open` a pop-up at a position based on the current window's screen position (`screenLeft`/`screen.left` etc). But pop-ups have many serious usability drawbacks and browsers limit their use for this reason.

Comment: Of course you can position an element outside the window. I want to animate it coming in

Comment: Ah! OK, fine. Well, then, the document-relative left position of the document is this: `0`. By definition. Screen-relative positioning is irrelevant for anything but pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to tell "left" what measure your statement is in (px, %, etc)