# Need to position div element outside document area not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Position element through css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531489/position-element-through-css)

Im have a problem with css positioning

```
jQuery(this).css({"left": (jQuery(document).css("left") - jQuery(form).width())});
```

Im getting an error with this jQuery(document).css("left") i could just put zero but i want to know the correct way of doing it

Comment: Are you double posting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531489/position-element-through-css

Comment: @PeeHaa, indeed an exact duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

You won't be positioning the document absolutely, so the `left` style attribute won't give you anything useful. Besides, you would not get a numerical value, but a string including the unit, so it couldn't be used in the subtraction anyway.

Use the `position` function instead:

```
jQuery(this).css({"left": (jQuery(document).position().left - jQuery(form).width()) + 'px' });
```

Comment: error object does not support this method or property so what could it be

Comment: @Gaby: That was what I remembered it as, it took some time to look up the exact syntax. They added some "smart" feature to the docs that captures arrow keys, so it's painfully slow to scroll down the page...

Comment: @littleMan: Which? Did you notice that I edited the code?

Comment: position is null or not an object thats the error I get. Im trying position an element outside a window to animate it coming in

Comment: @littleMan: I don't get the same error, but it seems that the position function is not supported with a jQuery created from the document object. You can use `$('body').position().left` to get the position of the body element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even really need to specify the 0, you can just negate the width of the form. If you really want to use a value, but not 0, you could try screen.availLeft [Mozilla's spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.availLeft)

```
jQuery(this).css({"left": (-jQuery(form).width())});
```

or

```
jQuery(this).css({"left": (window.screen.availLeft-jQuery(form).width())});
```

Comment: I just keep getting errors. I want to animate a div element outside the document coming in

Comment: window.screen.availLeft gives me nothing